# Restructure objects in javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an `object` like this "model":

```
var model = {
    comments: {
        123: "I disagree on this",
        42563: "Sounds correct"
    },
    answer: {
        123: "No",
        87: "Yes"
    }
};
```

I need to restructure the "model" `object` to this:

```
var wishModel = {
    123: {
        answer: "No",
        comments: "I disagree on this"
    },
    87: {
        answer: "Yes"
    },
    42563: {
        comments: "Sounds correct"
    }
};
```

I am pretty new in working with javascript `objects` and don't know where to start.

Comment: what is that 123 and 82 in JSON?

Comment: If you are so new to Javascript (objects) and don't know where to start, might I kindly suggest you google for some information

Comment: @GeorgeJempty You are right - tried google, but I didn't realy know how to describe the issue. Anyway I got some help here, greatful for that!

Comment: I think if you are struggling to work with Javascript objects, you probably need some sort of general Javascript primer, as opposed to just trying to find the answer to your specific problem

Comment: I know you're right George..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can loop through the objects using `for..of` like below

```js
var model = {
  comments: {
    123: "I disagree on this",
    42563: "Sounds correct"
  },
  answer: {
    123: "No",
    87: "Yes"
  }
};

let wishModel = {}

for(let [k,v] of Object.entries(model)) {
  for(let [n, r] of Object.entries(v)) {
    wishModel[n] = wishModel[n] || {}
    wishModel[n][k] = r
  }
}

console.log(wishModel)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitish - excellent, this I actually almost under stand :D

Answer (score -1):

Here's a newbie-compliant way:

```
var wishModel = {};

for (var key of ["comments", "answer"]) {
  for (var prop in model[key]) {
    wishModel[prop] = wishModel[prop] || {};
    wishModel[prop][key] = model[key][prop];
  }
}
```